# New update to minecraft realms

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I joined a friend's realm and spent a huge amount of time creating, mining, etc and now he tells me the world will be gone as he is updating to the new realm. I was shocked. I asked how I would keep my stuff and he said there is no way. He says it starts over from scratch and this is how he likes it. He is correct?  He said he would have to hire someone to move my stuff and he will not do that. Really?  Since I am just a player in his realm, I have no choice?  Can I somehow take my stuff and move to someone else's realm or another version?  He is on xbox and I am on PC if that matters. He says it is not java but is 1.16 version.   :(

Comment: If he's using Xbox I don't think he can give you the world because you can't access the Xbox files.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the owner of a realm can save a world copy of the realm (I know this because when I used to run a realm, I would make weekly world copies of the realm's progress), but I don't believe there's a way for them to transfer the world copy to you for ownership.

Comment: Is there a tutorial to do this?  He is willing to try but says he has never done it and he doesn't want his stuff to advance. He would let me take my stuff, but how would it know what I did and what he did?  Thanks for your help. I am 70 and am playing with my grandson and this is special to me but I don't have the energy to start over and I am discouraged about continuing to play if it just goes away.  TIA

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've last done this, so I'm a bit rusty on it.     Though if I could recall, the realm's owner would have to click the pencil icon next to their realm on the worlds menu, it would bring them to a menu with various realms information and options, they would find a tab called "backups", then it'd bring up a list of existing backups with a save icon button next to each one.     Clicking the save icons starts a download for a SinglePlayer world save of the realm backup, which would appear on their usual created worlds list.

Comment: If the owner wants to make a backup of their most recent backup, then they would need click on the top backup in the "Backups" menu (since their ordered from most recent to oldest).   1:33-2:28 of this video shows this process in action: https://youtu.be/pzmlFsMNh8E

Comment: If the realm's owner was using Windows 10 Edition or perhaps even Pocket Edition (to an extent) then they would probably be able to use programs of some kind to allow the world's file be available for you, however an Xbox player is severely limited with what they can do with world files, so I'm not sure how you would be able to get the world file that comes from when the owner downloads their realm backup unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you BlueTangsRock for all your work and responses. :)

Comment: No problem, Best of wishes to you with this situation

Answer (score 0):

If you are not the owner of a realm than the owner of that realm can do stuff like that and you just cannot do anything about that.

But what you could do was try to write down what you made and maybe try to remake that realm.